# In Rails how do I swap images using the image_tag and JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using `rails 6` and `ruby 3.1.1` My app is running on Heroku.

I have two images: `plus.png`, which is a `+` symbol and `minus.png`, a `-` symbol. Both are in `assets/images`.

When my view loads, the `+` image shows. When a user clicks on the image I want to change it to the `-` image - and vise-versa. In my code, I'm just trying to get it to change from `+` to `-` to start.

```
in my view:

<%= image_tag('plus.png', :size => '15x15', :id => "img-white") %>
```

```
in my application.js

$('#img-white').click(function(){
  $(this).attr("src", "<%= asset_path('minus.png') %>");
});
```

I got the `asset_path` part from another thread on Stackoverflow, but this just produces a broken image in my view.

How can I make this work?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does it not work by doing: `$(this).attr('src', 'minus.png')` ?

Comment: @Paul T  No, thanks, though.  That does not work.

Comment: Can you try debugging it so that you render an `<img>` tag with `asset_path("minus.png")` as source and see if ti breaks? If it breaks it means that the path is wrong.